# Why does calling a method from within a method avoid printing in new line?

Tags: bash

Here is an example script I made to illustrate what I mean when I say that I'm having trouble understanding why echo does not print in new line when calling a method from within another method:

```
prints_new_lines(){
echo hello
echo hello2
echo $(does_not_print_new_lines)
}

does_not_print_new_lines(){
echo here
printf "\n"
echo here2
}

prints_new_lines
```

I added the printf "\n" to see if that would work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the newline, you need to do:

```
echo "$(does_not_print_new_lines)"
```

i.e. with quotes.

It has nothing to do with calling from within a function, and everything to do with quoting.

Explanation:

Without quotes, your echo command basically translates to:

```
echo here\
here2
```

i.e. the shell sees a single command, `echo`, with 2 arguments, `here` and `here2`, separated by some whitespace - newline in this case.

So it just calls

```
echo 'here' 'here2'
```

Which is why you don't see a newline.

But with quotes, the command translates to

```
echo "here\
here2"
```

i.e. the shell sees a single command, `echo`, with 1 argument:

```
here
here2
```

So it calls

```
echo 'here
here2'
```

And you get your newline.

FWIW you should probably just drop the `echo` and use

```
does_not_print_new_lines
```

instead.

Comment: Great explanation @root. Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.